# MACアドレスは変えてよい？

Tags: virtualbox

- https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/01/11/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-an-ethernet-interface/

例えば**eth0**のMAC addressを変更する方法の１つとして

```
$ ifconfig eth0 down
$ ifconfig eth0 hw ether 08:00:00:00:00:01
$ ifconfig eth0 up
```

#### 質問１

このようにできますがこれはターミナルの**再起動**、もしくはパソコン自体を**再起動**することで戻るのでしょうか？

- https://tech.nikkeibp.co.jp/it/article/COLUMN/20070117/258977/

こちらでは**一時的**とありますが戻るタイミングについて書かれていません。

#### 質問２

MACアドレスが例えば自分の携帯(iphone)とかぶった際はどういった問題が考えられるのでしょうか？

#### 質問３

VirtualBoxで別のOSを触っている状態でそこで例えば**wlan0**のMAC addressを変えるとホストには影響はないのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問が3つありますが、それぞれの関連性が薄く（MACアドレスという点しか共通点がない）、散らかってる印象を受けます。それぞれ別の質問に分けたほうが良いと思います。

Comment: 仮想環境(VirtualBox)を使っているようですが、変更するつもりのMACアドレスがホストOSなのかゲストOSなのかを明記しておいた方が良い気がします。

Comment: すいません、MACアドレスがホストOSなのかゲストOSなのかが自分でもわかりません。virtualboxでterminalを開いてifconfigで変える前提です

Answer (score 5, accepted):

物理ネットワークカードにおいては MAC アドレスのデフォルト値はネットワークカード上の EEPROM に書き込まれています。

A1. デバイスドライバは EEPROM から RAM 上に MAC アドレスを持ってきて、その RAM 上の値を使って通信を行っています。 `ifconfig` がネットワークカードの EEPROM を書き換えちゃうなら、電源再投入後も書き換えたアドレスが採用されるでしょう。単に RAM 上の値を書き換えるだけなら、電源再投入で元のアドレスに戻るでしょう。なので `ifconfig` の実装次第。まあ普通は後者。物理ネットワークカードベンダが提供している MAC アドレス変更ツールであれば前者でしょう。

A2. 同一 MAC アドレスが同一 HUB に接続されたら誤動作します。無線でも同様。通信できなくなると考えて OK 。なのでその辺は完全に自己責任です。

A3. 仮想 OS 上の仮想ネットワークカードの MAC アドレスを書き換えても、物理ホスト上の物理ネットワークカードの MAC アドレスは変わらないです。仮想 HUB (この場合、物理ホスト上で動作しているネットワークブリッジドライバ) の MAC アドレスとたまたま同じ値を設定してしまうと A2 と同様、通信不能に陥ります。自己責任以下同文。

Comment: ありがとうございます、'ifcondig'の実装次第とありますがMACBOOKの場合はどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: オイラが過去に使った商用 Unix や Linux の全てで、電源を入れなおすと元に戻りました。心配なら `ifconfig eth0` で現在値が表示されるはずなので、メモしてから変更、電源断して再確認。

Comment: わかりました！！ありがとうございます！